# How to route to Child controller overridden API instead of Base Controller API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices

I have a class library and having a set of API Controllers in this class library.

There is a set of `.NET Core` `Microservices` that use this class library and if they want can override the Controller Action Methods in their implementation.

Base Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual string Get()
    {
        return "From Base class";
    }
}
```

Child Controller:

```
public class ChildController: BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "From Child class";
    }
}
```

Now my question is, if I browse "http://localhost:60634/base", then it should hit Child Controller Get API instead of Base controller Get API.

I thought of using redirection routing but did not find any such blog for .NET Core Microservice.

Please help.

Comment: normally base API controllers don't have their own routes and they always contain the abstract login, any specific reason you wanted to have a routing for your base class and separate routing for the child controller class

Comment: Since you are using `base` in the url, it will invoke method from base controller. If you have two child controllers, there will be confusion of which child controller method to call. So what you are asking for is not a practical use case. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Saravanan  This API is for HealthCheck. Certain Microservices does not want to override this implementation. They want to go as it is implemented in the Base Controller.


But some Microservices want to override the implementation. But I want to redirect the base class Route to Child Class Method is the call happens to Base Class too.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya This API is for HealthCheck. Certain Microservices does not want to override this implementation. They want to go as it is implemented in the Base Controller. But some Microservices want to override the implementation. 
But I want to redirect the base class Route to Child Class Get APU if the call happens to Base Class Get API

Comment: @SAnilKumarDora You should have individual URLs for health check of each microservice. With your approach the question still remains, which child class method should be called if there are more than one child classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    public virtual string HealthCheck()
    {
        return "From Base class";
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("Base")]
public class ChildController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public override string HealthCheck()
    {
        return "From Child class";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{

    [Route("~/Base/Get")]
        public virtual string Get()
    {
        return  "From Base class";
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class ChildController : BaseController
{
    [Route("~/Child/Get")]
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "From Child class";
    }
}
```